# How much (roughly) would it be for a bus from Shanghai, China, to Hanoi, Vietnam?

Tags: china, buses, shanghai

I have a flight from Canada to Bangkok, but a layover in Shanghai, China. I want to get off in Shanghai and spend a couple days there and catch a bus from there to Hanoi, Vietnam. However, I don't want to do this if it's going to be expensive. How much should it roughly cost for a couple nights in Shanghai and a bus ticket (I eat cheap, like rice with soy sauce for lunch and dinner)

Comment: I hope you understand about rules for getting off a flight before the ticketed destination.  If it is round trip and you get off in Shanghai, your return portion back to Canada will be automatically cancelled.  If it is a one way, they have the right to reprice the ticket to Shanghai instead of Bangkok and charge you the difference.

Comment: There is no bus between shanghai and Hanoi, you have to change bus in Nanning

Comment: @mts A 2 day bus ride through Asia? - yes please - I and my camera(s) would like that. (As long as it does not sit for most of the journey on motoways between tall berms as I've experienced on some occasions :-) - but not likely for much of that trip, I'd imagine.

Comment: Train may be viable and potentially superior.

Comment: Jake - Whatever you end up doing -  DO take the Shanghai Maglev trip at least once. Along the way observe the vehicles on the motorway as they whizz past doing 100 kph (road relative) but  backwards at almost 300 kph you-relative due to your speed. AND at the half way point you pass the second train going the other way - band waddawaddawadda (whatever) gone. Time it mentally - and then when you arrive look how long your train is and note that what you timed was the time for one such train to pass you. Astounding. On video it's "a few" frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Shanghai/Hanoi), the bus will take **37 hours** and cost around $150, with at least 2 or 3 layovers. A direct flight should cost $250 and take around 3 hours.

[image]